# Element moving on scroll causing horizontal scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm working on a website from a company and made one element move when you are scrolling. I implemented this by using jquery. The problem I have right now is that it's causing a lot of horizontal scroll because the element keeps moving the further down you get.

Is there a way to stop the scrolling once the element is no longer in view? Or give it a max distance it can move? I feel like I've been staring at it for too long now and can't figure it out.

```js
$(function () {
    var window_width = $(window).width() - $('#square_scroll01').width();

    var document_height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
        var object_position_left = window_width * ((scroll_position / document_height) * 3);
        $('#square_scroll01').css({
            'left': object_position_left
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.hero {
    background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/5U_28ojjgms/1600x900) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
}

.hero-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
}

.p1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.p2 {
  color: #000;
}

#square_scroll01 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 9.5%;
    bottom: -1.8%;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background: #7AC143;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="hero">
        <div class="container-lg">
            <div class="hero-content col-lg-6">
                <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-light ">Creating boundless communication together</h1>
                <p class="p1">Qet has minim elitr intellegat. Mea aeterno eleifend antiopam ad, nam no suscipit quaerendum. At nam minimum ponderum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum.</p>
                    <p class="p1">Qet has minim elitr intellegat. Mea aeterno eleifend antiopam ad, nam no suscipit quaerendum. At nam minimum ponderum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum.</p>
                    <p class="p1">Qet has minim elitr intellegat. Mea aeterno eleifend antiopam ad, nam no suscipit quaerendum. At nam minimum ponderum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum.</p>
    
                    <p class="p1">Qet has minim elitr intellegat. Mea aeterno eleifend antiopam ad, nam no suscipit quaerendum. At nam minimum ponderum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum.</p>
                    
                    <p class="p2">Qet has minim elitr intellegat. Mea aeterno eleifend antiopam ad, nam no suscipit quaerendum. At nam minimum ponderum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum.</p>
                    <p class="p2">Qet has minim elitr intellegat. Mea aeterno eleifend antiopam ad,  nam no suscipit quaerendum. At nam minimum ponderum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum. Qet has minim elitr intellegat. Mea aeterno eleifend antiopam ad,  nam no suscipit quaerendum. At nam minimum ponderum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum. Qet has minim elitr intellegat. Mea aeterno eleifend antiopam ad,  nam no suscipit quaerendum. At nam minimum ponderum. Est audiam animal molestiae te. Ex duo eripuit mentitum.</p>
                <div class="justify-content-md-start">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-light btn-md px-4 me-md-2">Contact
                        us</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="square_scroll01">
        </div>
    </section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cutlasskiwi/kcvypj82/49/

Comment: I dont understand why you are using Jquery for this, it can all be done in CSS. Can you explain a bit more what it is you want it to do?

Comment: I took over the project from a developer that since left the company and he left a skeleton of a website with some of the jquery added. I just finished it. How do I limit the scrolling with just css instead? Like I said, I feel like I've been staring at this for too long now.

Comment: @SandraFrandén Is there something specific that this element is being used for? I ask because at various screen sizes the element either does what you've described in your problem or it does nothing at all. There's a jquery method of limiting horizontal scroll position but it only works in Firefox which wouldn't be a good idea. And welcome to SO! :)

Comment: @AStombaugh Thanks! :) 

It's being used as a "cool looking thing" because the owner of the website really loves this green little square moving when your scroll. And he really wants it to be there, at least on desktop but preferably on on devices.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `overflow-x: hidden;` either on `body` or on a known ancestor element parent
- Use `transform: translate` to *move* your element, since that can be GPU accelerated and less choppy than by using properties like `left`.

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  const $square = $('#square_scroll01'); // Cache your elements!!
  const availWidth = $(window).width() - $square.width();
  const docHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    const posX = availWidth * scrollTop / docHeight * 3;
    $square.css({
      transform: `translateX(${posX}px)`
    });
  });

});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hero {
  background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/5U_28ojjgms/1600x900) no-repeat center center / cover;
  height: 100vh;
  /*width: 100vw; /* UNNECESSARY */
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

#square_scroll01 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 9.5%;
  bottom: -1.8%;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #7AC143;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<section class="hero container-lg">
  <div class="hero-content col-lg-6">
    <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-light">Creating boundless communication together</h1>
    <p class="p1" style="height: 200vh;">Just some tall content... Scroll down...</p>
    <div class="justify-content-md-start">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-light btn-md px-4 me-md-2">Contact us</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="square_scroll01"></div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```